# How to display total automatically without submit button?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am very new at JavaScript so a step by step answer would be much appreciated. Right now my code is set up so when you click the submit button it displays the total but instead I would like the total to be updated automatically by just checking the checkboxes and to not have a submit button at all.

```
function calcTotal()
{
  var itemTotal = 0;
  var items = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (items[i].checked){
      itemTotal += parseInt(items[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Your order total is $" + itemTotal +".00";
}
var submitButton = document.getElementById("sButton");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", calcTotal);
```

Comment: You can bind the function to each checkbox' `change` event instead.

Comment: You could use `object.addEventListener("keyup", calcTotal);` That means as you type in your numbers, the information will update live.

Comment: And please post your html code so that we can reproduce your situation and provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key is listening to the `input` event on the input elements instead of the `click` event on the button element.

Additional notes, when possible:

- Use single quotes in JS, double quotes in HTML
- Use `let` or `const` instead of `var`
- Don't reinvent `.reduce` when you need to *reduce* an array of values into a single value (e.g. compute a sum).
- Use template strings (e.g. `` `y: ${y}` ``) instead of concatenating strings (e.g. `"y: " + y`).

```js
let inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("input")];

let calcTotal = () => {
  let sum = inputs.reduce((sum, input) => sum + (input.checked ? parseInt(input.value) : 0), 0);
  document.querySelector("#total").textContent = `Your order total is $${sum}.00`;
};

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', calcTotal));
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value=30>$30 hamburger</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value=45>$45 french fries</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value=1>$1 cola</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value=60>$60 parking</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value=20>$20 cookie</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value=290>$290 large cookie</label>
<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you I tried your method on the original project and it worked but now that I am trying it on another project it's not working for some reason.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to bind Checkbox's event `change`, instead of Form submit button `click`. That whenever you change checkbox value by checking or unchecking it, It call the function `calcTotal()` to update the value.

Here is updated Javascript code:

```
function calcTotal()
{
  var itemTotal = 0;
  var items = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (items[i].checked){
      itemTotal += parseInt(items[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Your order total is $" + itemTotal +".00";
}
var checkBoxItems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
checkBoxItems.addEventListener("change", calcTotal);
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a change event to every checkbox. When you toggle the checked state, recalculate the total by grabbing the `:checked` checkboxes.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')).forEach(chk => {
  chk.addEventListener('change', recalculateTotal);
});

function recalculateTotal() {
  let total = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(':checked')).reduce((sum, chk) => {
    return sum + parseInt(chk.value, 10);
  }, 0);
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = '$' + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
label { display: inline-block; margin-right: 1em; }
div { margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<label>$1 <input type="checkbox" value="1" /></label>
<label>$10 <input type="checkbox" value="10" /></label>
<label>$100 <input type="checkbox" value="100" /></label>
<div>Your order total is: <span id="total">$0.00</span></div>
```